# RStudio creates the graph, but Markdown will not

Tags: plot, markdown

I'm running a very short snippet of code and I can create the graph in the RStudio plot window, but when I run the Markdown, I get the following error:

> Error in hist(p.rating): object 'p.rating' not found

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
{r loading data, include=FALSE}

setwd("~/Google Drive/New Leaders/Data/KnownGroups")

mydata <- read.csv("Copy of Gates Study Data Download (052815_v2).csv")

attach(mydata)

colnames(mydata)[5] <- "p.rating"



{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}

hist(p.rating)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see `p` much less `p.rating` defined anywhere in your code snippet... if that's all the code, then the error makes perfect sense.

Comment: OK, I get it... you're naming column 5 of the mydata "p.rating" ... but it's still just a column name.  How about `hist(mydata$p.rating)`

Comment: What a neophyte mistake ... that makes sense. I'm a neophyte here. Thanks so much - worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The histogram statement at the end has just the column name without the data set. This should help:

`hist(mydata$p.rating)`